# Crystal Reports - Remove Excess Records

Tags: crystal-reports

Good day everyone. I would like to ask for help regarding printing records using Crystal Reports.

My aim is to print all the records in the report. The problem is that when I have only two or three records, the form will still print a space to forcibly expand it into a one whole page.

What I have did is to manually place all the parameters in the form, and add a record number parameter built in the Crystal Reports Designer. I loaded a dummy record with nothing in it. Now when I run a report wherein I have only two to three records, I have this output.

[image: My Delivery Receipt with only one record.]

How will I work out this problem? I can only find in the Internet about shrinking, but not expanding.

Comment: can you reword your question please- it's unclear. it sounds like you're saying you don't want the dummy records- but you added them in... so i'm confused. crystal default behaviour will not add dummy records to fill the page.

Comment: Let's just say the question is how will I make the whole form fit to page when all I have is only one record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Section Expert, check 'Suppress Blank Section'. Hope that helps